# how to deindex specific category in opencart through robots.txt file

Tags: php, opencart, robots.txt

Hello if i am not wrong robots.txt file will be this for opencart

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*&limit
Disallow: /*&sort
Disallow: /*?route=checkout/
Disallow: /*?route=account/
Disallow: /*?route=product/search
Disallow: /*?route=affiliate/
Allow: /
```

I want to de-index a category from my site so what code i use in robots.txt file to remove that category from google. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open `/catalog/controller/product/category.php`

Find this line

```
if ($category_info) {
```

On a new line after it add this

```
if ($category_info['category_id'] == 123) {
     header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex", true);
}
```

changing `123` to the category id of the one you want to stop indexing